# Smooth scrolling of text (Autoscroll) in UITextView iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, smooth-scrolling

I am working on a project where I there is some text in UItextview. The app wants to continuous smooth scroll that text and also wants to manage its scrolling speed. I mean here the text should scroll smoothly and the app contains slider where I can manage the speed. 
Below is some sample code which I am using.

```
- (void) autoscrollTimerFired:(NSTimer *)timer {
    [self.completeText setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0, self.completeText.contentOffset.y + 1.0) animated:NO];
    if (self.completeText.contentOffset.y != self.completeText.contentSize.height - self.completeText.frame.size.height) {
        scrollingTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:velocityFactor target:self selector:@selector(autoscrollTimerFired:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    } else {
        [scrollingTimer invalidate];
    }
}
```

The Velocity factor is the number of seconds which ranges between 0.0 to 2.5.

It works nice in simulator but in device it moves with jerks or I must say like pausing at after some line. 
Could you please suggest any solution here? All suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

The NSTimers actually just periodically fire events into the enclosing NSRunLoop, which each thread has (or should have). So, if you have a child (or background) process running in a different thread, the NSTimers will fire against that thread's NSRunLoop instead of the application's main NSRunLoop.

NSTimer events fire on the thread where you scheduled the timer. If you scheduled the timer on the main run loop, then the timer will fire on the main thread and be “safe and synced” with input events.

So I have some suggestions for try that (I am not sure how much it will be successful in your case)

Don't use NSTimer. Try to call from main thread via selector with "afterDelay". As given in code

```
[self performSelector:@selector(autoScroll) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

Use KVO or may be NSNotification for event triggering. (Not do it directly ,I Think better approach.)

I prefers KVO , so writing here the steps to use it :-
Make a class with a variable of NSNumber (which should accessible outside the class). Make a object of that class and add a Observer on it. (here model is object of that class).

```
[model addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"name" options:(NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld |
                                                     NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew) context:nil];
```

Implements it's delegate methods.

```
-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
                 ofObject:(id)object
                   change:(NSDictionary *)change
                  context:(void *)context
{
  // Do here what ever you want to do. It will call every time whenever there will be  any change in that class variable.
}
```

Make a method in controller "autoScroll" which called via afterDelay selector. And change the value of the NSNumber vairabe value (any logic incremental way. Doesn't affect a lot).

Hope this helps you !!! Try This ...best of luck

Comment: Thanks for your response Arpit. But changing NSTimer to performselector is a very long process where I need to change many logics which I am doing on after completion of NSTimer and scroll. Can we do something with NSTimer so that it can work same in device as Simulator

Comment: Yes, You need to understand from thread , you making the NSTimer object and from which you sheduling it. Try to call it from main thread not from other. Because NSRunloop here tries to break other runloop at the same time. Spend some ours on NSTimer "threading" concept. SO I think you can use it in better way.

Comment: Read this too :- http://iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/73746-using-nstimer-in-threading.html